# How do i send back the received messeage to all other coneccted clients(threads)?

Tags: python, multithreading

i wanna send back the received messeage to all other connected clients in this code?
The received messeage only goes to the server right now and thats not good.
Is there like any way to use just variables for that? if yes it would be  nice if someone could edit my code!
I dont know how to use things like shared memory so please help, thanks!

```
import time
import threading

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("192.168.0.88", 187))
s.listen(10)




def lol():
    try:
        print(threading.current_thread())#accept connection
        while True:
            client, adress = s.accept()
            print("connected")
            time.sleep(1)
            client.send(bytes("Welcome", "utf8"))



            def get_input():#send messeages
                while True:
                    data = input()  # Something akin to this
                    client.send(bytes(data, "utf8"))

            input_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_input)
            input_thread.start()



            while True:#receive messeage
                try:
                    recmes = bytes.decode(client.recv(1024), "utf8")
                    print(recmes)




                except:
                    print("disconnected")
                    lol()
    except:
        lol()


saas = threading.Thread(target=lol)#Connect space1
saas2 = threading.Thread(target=lol)#Connect space2
saas3 = threading.Thread(target=lol)#Connect space3
saas4 = threading.Thread(target=lol)#Connect space4
saas5 = threading.Thread(target=lol)#Connect space5
saas6 = threading.Thread(target=lol)#Connect space6

saas.start()
saas2.start()
saas3.start()
saas4.start()
saas5.start()
saas6.start()
```

Comment: I don't see anything called `socket` defined in your code. Were there any errors?

Comment: the socket is defined as "s" and there were no errors. ijust want to send ack the received stuff to all threads ( clients). (iforgot to copy the "import socket" at the top)

Comment: Maybe make it so each time a socket connects, it pushes to an database, and each time one disconnects, pop it. That way, you can loop through and send the data to each.